# How can I list all tasks that are available for a user?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to query all the tasks that the user hasn't done yet.

I create a model called state

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  as_enum :value, %i{available inprogress completed}
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task
end
```

class User and class Task has a has_many relationship with class state.

I've tried to do this and I was able to end up with an array as shown below:

```
@tasks = []
current_user.states.where(value_cd: 0).each do |task|
      @tasks << state.task
end
```

how would I be able to do this with a query?

My hope is to achieve something similar to this:

```
Tasks.where(state.value: :available && state.user_id == current_user.id)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know Ruby on rails.. But i do know SQL you need to use a LEFT JOIN

Comment: Do Users and Tasks have a relationship?

Comment: By the way, what is `as_enum`? Is that a backport for Rails' modern enum functionality? If you're using Rails 4.1+ (?) then this is now a native feature; you can drop the third party gem.

Comment: In addition, if you're referencing enums *by their number*, then you're sort of missing the point!... The whole idea is that "the computer" uses numbers, and "the human" uses meaningful names. So in this case (depending on the actual library you're using), it should be possible to do something like: `states.available` instead of `states.where(value_cd: 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it at the moment, but I believe you want to use [includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes).
Something like this should then work:

```
tasks = Task.includes(:states).where(states: { value: :available, user_id: current_user.id})
```

You can also read more about specifying conditions [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)

<s>But if I'm not mistaken you could also just get all tasks that a user has not done yet this way too:</s>

```
current_user.tasks.map(&:states).map(&:available)
```

- [engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky) says I am mistaken.

Comment: The first one is good. the second should be deleted completely

Comment: Because of mapping twice over the whole collection or because it wouldn't give the wanted results?

Comment: Both to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Update your `User` models with the dedicated scope:

```
has_many :available_tasks, -> { where('state.id' => 0) }, through: :state
```

And use:

```
current_user.tasks
```

Or use:

```
Tasks.joins(:state).where(
  'state.value' => 0,
  'state.user_id' => current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Task
  has_many :states
end

Task.joins(:states).where(states: {user_id: current_user.id, value: :available})
Task.joins(:states).where.not(states: {value: :completed})
    .where(states: {user_id: current_user.id})
```

This approach starts by identifying that what you want the result to be is a collection of Tasks.  So you want to query the Task model to give you that result.

The `current_user.states` association would allow you to query states, but you need to chain that to a query on tasks, so chaining associations won't get you where you want to get.